# What are the responsibilities of a project manager in a DevOps project?

Tags: team-management, project-management-style, product-management, devops

How can a project manager foster greater accountability between empowered DevOps personnel and empowered developers in an Agile environment?

I work in an environment where both developers and DevOps personnel have a lot of autonomy. They need to work together to ensure a stable and complian build and deployment pipeline. It seems a project manager can help create the right communication between the two. But I'm running into the situation where the project manager is having trouble getting the two groups to work well together.

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand your first sentence.

Comment: Can we check your definition of "Project" first? Do you mean "A project to create a DevOps environment and process"?. Or do you mean "A project to manage the ongoing DevOps process and release of code"? The first is a project, the second is operations.

Comment: I'm tempted to close this as unclear, but think there's a good question in here somewhere. I want to give the OP (or the community) 1-2 business days to improve it.

Comment: @JoelBancroft-Connors Frankly my goal is not to produce a neologism. A project DEVOPS of what I understand is a project that has a beginning and an end, it is a temporary effort to create a product or a unique result and that uses the concept DEVOPS to produce a software.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I hope I brought you more detail

Comment: There is no defined role called "Project Manager" in DevOps culture or agile frameworks.

Comment: Edited for greater clarity of OP's believed intent. Please @AtmaneElBouachri please let us know if this is close to what you're getting at.

Comment: @MarkPhillips Thank you. Yes, more or less. I accept.

Comment: @RubberDuck I would be grateful if you made the effort to explain the DEVOPS to me in simple words. Sorry for my pitiful English, I'm not english native speaker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

DevOps and project management are very separate practices and knowledge domains that can borrow from each other. Any other answer is likely an opinion about process implementation.

### DevOps Isn't a Synonym for Agile Project Management

DevOps is primarily a culture of collaboration between diverse roles such as requirements analysis, testing, development, deployment, operations, and maintenance. To a lesser extent, it is also a set of tools and practices for enabling rapid feedback for collaboration, and providing delivery and deployment pipelines.

Project management as a practice or profession is the art of planning and controlling projects. To the extent that DevOps provides a framework for product delivery, and to the extent that it creates feedback loops and process controls, a project manager can leverage the framework and controls when planning, organization, or measuring the project. However, DevOps as a culture or as a tool chain has no defined role for a project manager, making the question as asked confusing and vague.

You can implement a project without agile frameworks or practices. Likewise, a given framework like Scrum or Kanban does not rely on DevOps culture, tools, or practices to provide process controls. Borrowing sensible tools and practices from DevOps to create feedback or processs controls within an agile framework is often wise, though.

Even though there is no defined role titled "Project Manager" in DevOps culture or agile frameworks, that doesn't mean a project manager can't leverage them. However, if you're going outside the formal definitions, then your mileage may vary.

Comment: I agree that DEVOPS and project management are two separate things. Also, DevOps can work with both an Agile and Waterfall. Indeed, it will ensure that every sprint or each stage of the waterfall is crossed in the fastest possible way once the code for this stage is ready. But here we are talking about the software engineering [DEV/Development]. This is why I can not disassociate a DEVOPS implementation from a project. So, we can raise the question whether the DevOps can be used outside software engineering? But for now I want to restrict this methodology in a project management framework.